# How to validate equality of rounding values in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Unable to get status of total amount and paid amount. Paid status functionality not working proper. Please see the image below.

[Wrong Status Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKeEj.png)

Here is my code

```
$total_amount = $row->total;
$paid = $row->paid_amount;

if($paid > '0.00'){
 echo '<span class="label label-warning">Partial</span>';   
} elseif($total_amount != $paid) {
 echo '<span class="label label-primary">Unpaid</span>';
} elseif($total_amount == $paid ){
 echo '<span class="label label-success">Paid</span>';
}
```

Please help me to fix this problem. Its my school project and it need to be submitted tomorrow.

Comment: PHP evaluate your condition from top to bottom, this case your `$paid` is `40` and it more than 0, so it shows `Partial` and stop there. So the code runs correctly, just not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing floating point numbers is usually problematic as there are precision issues.  There are additional issues in the order of your if/elseif statements. These statements will execute top to bottom entering only the first matched block.  I would change your code as follows to round your values, reorder your if statements and compare with either `<` or `>=` :

```
$total_amount = round($row->total, 2);
$paid = round($row->paid_amount, 2);

if ($paid <= 0){
  echo '<span class="label label-primary">Unpaid</span>';
} elseif ($paid < $total_amount) {
  echo '<span class="label label-warning">Partial</span>';   
} elseif ($paid >= $total_amount) {
  echo '<span class="label label-success">Paid</span>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for improving my code but you also make it a little wrong as $total_amount < $paid is need to correct like this $paid < $total_amount.

Comment: Good catch, additionally the last `elseif` could probably just be `else`, but its functionally equivalent.

Comment: Yeah you are right but  `elseif` looks more comfortable. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @AlexBarker: comparing floating point is not the only issue with OP's code, the logic behind the `if` is broken as well. Since you also fix the `if-else` condition with this solution, it's would be great if you can add that to your explanation so that it could help future users.